# Type conversions of a void pointer for pointer arithmetics

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, const-pointer

For using pointer arithmetics the type of a void pointer is converted multiple times.

The vector containing the data comes from an external source and returns a void pointer to access its data. Furthermore, the stride is also given by the external object and it heeds alignment requirements. To keep the example short it *does not* fully reflect those two facts.

```
// Example data from external source.
struct Data {
    float x;
    float y;

    Data() : x(5), y(8) {}
};

// Example vector from external source.
size_t elements = 3;
std::vector<Data> list;
list.resize(elements);

// Pointer conversions.
const void * voidPointer = list.data(); // The external object containing the vector returns a void pointer.
const uint8_t * countPointer = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(voidPointer);

// Pointer arithmetics.
unsigned stride = sizeof(Data); // The external object returning the stride heeds alignment requirements.
for (size_t counter = 0; counter < elements; ++counter, countPointer += stride) {
    const float * pointsToFloatX = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(countPointer);
    printf("%f, ", *pointsToFloatX); // Expecting something like 5.0000, 5.0000, 5.0000
}
```

The conversion to `uint8_t` does not affect the (`float`) data the pointer is pointing to since only the type of the pointer is converted?

Why `const` works on the `countPointer` though it gets incremented? Does `const` mean that the data the pointer points to may not be altered?

Why I have to use `reinterpret_cast<const float*>` instead of `static_cast<const float*>` to convert `countPointer` inside the loop?

Comment: Such kind of pointer manipulation is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlexD It might be legal if `&list[0]` had been used instead of `&list`

Comment: @MattMcNabb But the vector is of `Data` type. Casting `Data*` to `uint8_t*` (via `void*`) does not look OK.

Comment: @AlexD How would you do the pointer arithmetics when the type of the vector elements varies and the only information you have is the size of stride?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I've corrected the question.

Comment: @AlexD any type may be aliased by a character type , and character types do not have alignment requirements. Strictly speaking I'm not sure if going via `void *` is legal, but directly casting is legal.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But does `uint8_t` have to be `char`?

Comment: @AlexD it has to be a character type (probably `unsigned char`). All the non-character integer types are at least 16 bit

Comment: @MattMcNabb Do you mean in theory or in practice? If we take the standard literally, all types from `char` to `long long` could be 1 byte, no? Regardless of that, `struct` padding and alignment is a source of UB.

Comment: @AlexD `long long` could be 1 byte, but not `uint8_t` since it must have at least 64 bits.  `uint8_t` has no alignment requirements; and the `float *` must be correctly aligned because each member of a struct must be correctly aligned for itself. You could use a `static_assert` to double check there is no padding in `Data` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb Not 8 bits? O am I too sleepy?

Comment: @AlexD  the standard has minimum requirements for type sizes: `int` 16bit, `long` 32bit, `long long` 64bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84332/discussion-between-alexd-and-matt-mcnabb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The conversion to `uint8_t` does not affect the (`float`) data the pointer is pointing to since only the type of the pointer is converted?

That's right. But when casting pointers, keep in mind that there are alignment requirements. Also, note that `&list` points to `vector<Data>`; you would use `list.data()` to get the `Data*` array.

> Why `const` works on the `countPointer` though it gets incremented? Does `const` mean that the data the pointer points to may not be altered?

Yes. Write `float * const` to make the pointer itself constant or `const float * const` to get a constant pointer to constant data.

> Why I have to use `reinterpret_cast<const float*>` instead of `static_cast<const float*>` to convert `countPointer` inside the loop?

Compatible types can be cast with `static_cast`, for others use `reinterpret_cast`. `void*` is compatible with any other. Avoid using `reinterpret_cast` unless you are very sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: Nice answer to a somewhat rambling question!  +1

Comment: `uint8_t` and `float` are not compatible types b/c `uint8_t` has a shorter length in memory and therefore stores less information than `float`?

Comment: @RoiDanton, they are not compatible because `uint8_t` is not a base class for `float` and because there is no special rule that says they should be compatible (like there is for `void*` and enum/integral pointer conversion, for example).

Comment: @rholmes I've updated the question to tell why a void pointer is used in the example and where the stride comes from.